# How to run csscomb.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use Ubuntu 14.04. Installed node.js, npm csscomb, csscomb.js addition to Sublime Text 3, the path to the configuration file settings.
However, in step     `csscomb assets / css`     stay. Since the answer I receive     `/ usr / bin / env: node: No such file or directory`     As I understand it, the system does not see ccscomb? Already tried to reinstall everything in order, but to no avail.
Sublime by pressing a combination of ctrl + shift + c does not react in any way, even the mistakes writes.

I suspect that the problem may lie in the fact that I'm not familiar with node.js and may miss some basic steps. So, good people, help me understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly went wrong in your case so let's make sure that all tasks are performed correctly.

#### 1. Install `nodejs` on Ubuntu:

Open terminal and run this:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

Verify that `nodejs` is installed correctly and that symlink is present by running:

```
node --version
npm --version
```

If you don't see `nodejs` and `npm` vesion numbers (`v0.10.25` and `1.3.24` respectively), something went wrong with the installation. Post the message from your terminal and so that we can have a look.

#### 2. Install the `csscomb` itself globally

```
npm install csscomb -g
```

Verify:

```
csscomb --version
```

Again, you should see `csscomb` version number (currently `3.0.0`). Let us know if something went wrong here.

#### 3. Install `CSSComb` Sublime Package

I assume you have [Sublime Package Control installed](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation). Open Sublime Text 3, and press `Ctrl + Shift + P`. Type `install package` and press  enter. Then type `CSSComb` and press enter again. `CSSComb` package should be installed now.

Open any css file, select a few lines and press `Ctrl + Shift + C` to comb it.

---

Let me know if more detailed instruction for some of the actions is needed.

Comment: Use `chris-lea/node.js` for the repository, not the Ubuntu main ones. Those are out of date, and this one you only have to install node. Also, in Ubuntu, you will have to symlink /usr/bin/nodejs -> /usr/bin/node.

Comment: Not for ubuntu 13.04/13.10: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#ubuntu-mint-elementary-os `nodejs-legacy` package takes care of symlinks. Thanks @impinball for mentioning symlink issues. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Still, NPM is at 1.4 at this point, which Chris Lea's repository currently has.

Comment: 'node --version' does not work, but it works well: 'nodejs -version'

after 'npm install csscomb -g' - displaying the error 
'npm ERR! 404 'ccscomb' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-29-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "ccscomb" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /var/www/markup/www/TripleDry.pro
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! code E404'

Comment: Another dug and found that if you remove a sablayme path to the configuration file when you press the hotkey displays:
CSScomb error:
/home/kirill/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/CSScomb/node_modules/csscomb/node_modules/csscomb-core/lib/core.js:412
            throw e;
                  ^
Please check the validity of the block starting from line #2
2*|   background: #262626;
3 |   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #010101 100%);
Gonzales PE version: 3.0.0-10
CSScomb Core version: 2.0.2

Comment: @user3835746 the module is called `csscomb`, not `ccscomb`. Try this command again: `npm install csscomb -g`

Comment: @user3835746 also make sure that you have ubuntu package `nodejs-legacy` installed. This package contains a symlink for legacy Node.js code requiring binary to be `/usr/bin/node` (not `/usr/bin/nodejs` as provided in Ubuntu). You can install it using the following command: `sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy`.

Comment: @user3835746 `nodejs` version in Ubuntu repository is stable but not the latest. It should be more than enough for your needs though. Alternatively, you can consider installing `nodejs` from `chris-lea/node.js` PPA as mentioned by @impinball

Comment: @user3835746 try running Sublime Text 3 CSSComb package without the configuration file first. It should still work using default settings. After you verify that it works normally with default settings, try adding custom CSSComb configuration in Sublime Text package.

Comment: Finally it works. Reinstalled nodejs-legacy and csscomb again and it worked. Thanks guys!